# Java GUI Event Object Import

Tags: java, user-interface, object, events

I want a java gui event to, when activated, call a class for processing. I am having an issue because I need to use an object "Settings" that is created earlier in the code and have it for the rest of the program. Basically when types in textfield and presses enter, this event starts and calls a class to handle the user's input. I have looked at other forum answers and their solutions involve creating "new" objects, which is not what I am trying to do. Display.TaskInput needs the "Settings" object to work. This is the event:

```
public class event implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //The text below calls a task that needs to use the settings object
        //This object presets the task object for easier user input.
        //Yes, this is wrong, but you can see what I am trying to do.
        Display.TaskInput(settings);

        //The rest of this is just for testing. It works when the above line             
        //is removed.
        label.setText("This worked also");
        label2.setText("This worked also");
        panel1.add(label2);
        add(panel1);
        panel1.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

This is where the Settings Object is created. It is preset by a database. When the user enters a task, the task will have several presets ready so that the user does not have to manually enter them. This is the start of the program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     //object is created and loaded with data
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    DatabaseConnectSettingsSelect.Connect(settings);

    //this is where the gui is initiated. 
    FrameStart.main(args);

    //Once the gui starts working, this class will become unnecessary 
    Display.StartScreen(settings);
    }
```

This is the main in the GUI class FrameStart:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FrameStart ex = new FrameStart();
        ex.setVisible(true);   
    }
```

Everything would be fine if I didn't need to use a premade object. Most of the solutions could solve that, but I need to import an object created in another class. If you need more code to look at I happily provide it; this is just where the problem area is that I have run into.

To sum things up, I need to place an already created object into an event class or directly into the TaskInput class. Is there a better way than what I am doing? This program has about 15 classes and the way I am currently doing things works well, its just that I don't know how to place a created object into the ActionEvent code. Once again, I have looked at other forum answers and their solutions involve creating "new" objects which is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: You're naming convention is troubling and makes it look like your are relying entirely on `static` references, and if that is so, then don't.  You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Either `Settings` needs to be accessible via some kind of "central" controller (singleton for example) or you need to pass a reference to the `event` class when you construct it

Comment: `Display.StartScreen(settings);` and `DatabaseConnectSettingsSelect.Connect(settings);` seems to demonstrate that you know how to pass variables to other classes.  Instead of using `FrameStart.main`, make a constructor for `FrameStart` which takes a reference to `Settings` and use it

Comment: Ok I placed public ObjectSettings settings; at the start and have it in the constructor FrameStart(ObjectSettings settings). I am also changing most of the names for easier reading. So basically correct me if Im wrong, since the Object is made public, any method OR subclass in the class can use it hence the event class can then use it. Is that right?